# Effective C++: Item 52 and how to avoid hiding all normal operator new & delete versions

Tags: c++, memory-management

At the end of Item 52 (Customising new and delete) in Myer's Effective C++ he discusses how to avoid hiding normal new and delete versions when implementing custom version as follows:

> If you declare any operator news in a
>   class, you'll hide all these standard
>   forms. Unless you mean to prevent
>   class clients from using these forms,
>   be sure to make them available in
>   addition to any custom operator new
>   forms you create. For each operator
>   new you make available, of course, be
>   sure to offer the corresponding
>   operator delete, too. If you want
>   these functions to behave in the usual
>   way, just have your class-specific
>   versions call the global versions.
>
> An easy way to do this is to create a
>   base class containing all the normal
>   forms of new and delete:

```
class StandardNewDeleteForms {

public:

  // normal new/delete

  static void* operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc)

  { return ::operator new(size); }

  static void operator delete(void
*pMemory) throw()

  { ::operator delete(pMemory); }



  // placement new/delete

  static void* operator new(std::size_t size, void *ptr) throw()

  { return ::operator new(size, ptr); }

  static void operator delete(void
*pMemory, void *ptr) throw()

  { return ::operator delete(pMemory, ptr); }



  // nothrow new/delete

  static void* operator new(std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nt) throw()

  { return ::operator new(size, nt); }

  static void operator delete(void
*pMemory, const std::nothrow_t&) throw()

  { ::operator delete(pMemory); }

};
```

> Clients who want to augment the
>   standard forms with custom forms can
>   then just use inheritance and using
>   declarations (see Item 33) to get the
>   standard forms:

```
class Widget: public StandardNewDeleteForms {           // inherit std forms

public:

   using StandardNewDeleteForms::operator new;  // make those

   using StandardNewDeleteForms::operator delete;       // forms visible



   static void* operator new(std::size_t size,          // add a custom

                             std::ostream& logStream)   // placement new

     throw(std::bad_alloc);



   static void operator delete(void
*pMemory,           // add the corres-

                               std::ostream& logStream) // ponding place-

    throw();                                            // ment delete

  ...

};
```

Why go to the bother of creating the class StandardNewDeleteForms, inheriting from it and then in the derived class saying:

```
using StandardNewDeleteForms::operator new;
using StandardNewDeleteForms::operator delete;
```

Could you not forgo the base class altogether and simply write in the Widget class:

```
using ::operator new;
using ::operator delete;
```

to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would effectively be a no-op `using`. He's simply showing an implementation of the base class `new`/`delete` that would duplicate the normal behavior.

Usually if you're creating a custom `new` and `delete` you would have changed behavior in that base class and the `using ::operator new;` would no longer be equivalent. He didn't do that in his example so it's slightly less clear what's happening.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer although I didn't quite follow your points completely. You said: "That would effectively be a no-op using.", I didn't quite understand how you meant it would be effectively a no-op so I tried compiling what I proposed (using ::operator new;) and I get the error - 'operator new' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration'

So I guess that construct isn't allowed by the language specification at all, i.e. a using declaration for a class member can only refer to a member inherited from a base class. Is my thinking correct here?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not allowed to do `using ::operator new;` as it's not a member of parent class.

Second, the global new is'nt useful to overload because most of the time :
 1. you'll use libraries that use or not this operator, making a mess;
 2. you might want to use different new/delete code for different type of objects;

The idea behind this item is that you can change the new/delete behavior of classes that inherit the parent class, allowing changing allocation strategy for a whole group of classes.

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand most of your answer but in particular the first line? Maybe you can elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the same book and I wondered exactly the same thing!

It appears that the rules governing `using` depend on the context:

When used in a namespace it allows you to pull members from other namespaces, including the global namespace, into the new namespace ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)) :

```
 void f();
 namespace A {
   void g();
 }
 namespace X {
   using ::f;  // global f is now visible as ::X::f
   using A::g; // A::g is now visilbe as ::X::g
 }
 void h()
 {
   X::f(); // calls ::f
   X::g(); // calls A::g
 }
```

However, when used in a class definition as ([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)):

```
using nested-name-specifier
```

then

> nested-name-specifier must name a base class of the one being defined.